# Typescript complains that private property is not present in the interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, interface

I have a following very basic code:

```
interface EmployeeSalaryInterface {
    name: string
    hoursWorked: number
    readonly perHourRate: number
    calculateSalary(): string
}

class EmployeeSalary implements EmployeeSalaryInterface {
    private readonly perHourRate: number = 20

    constructor(private name: string, private hoursWorked: number) {}

    public calculateSalary(): string {
        return `Employee ${this.name} has a base salary of $${this.hoursWorked * this.hoursWorked} for working ${this.hoursWorked} a day`
    }
}
```

Now, typescript doesn't allow me to create private property in the interface. However, for some reason, if I implement that interface in a class with the private property, it throws `Class 'EmployeeSalary' incorrectly implements interface 'EmployeeSalaryInterface'. Property 'name' is private in type 'EmployeeSalary' but not in type 'EmployeeSalaryInterface'.ts(2420)`

[image]

If typescript doesn't allow to include access modifiers in interface then why does it complain?

Comment: It complains because your type does not implement the interface.

Comment: Why would you define a private property in an interface? It's not part of the public API.

Comment: @zerkms What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Sanjay your type does not implement the interface -> you don't get a type check exception. It's not obvious what exactly your problem is. You declared `name: string` field in the interface, your class does not implement it.

Answer (score 5):

An interface is a public agreement. The statement "Class A implements interface B" means: "any instance of class A **publish** all properties and methods from the interface B, so they are available for anyone using instance".

So, in your case typescript behavior is correct